# Load html View after Angular controller has finished loading async functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-scope

I am displaying a button that has conditional enable or disable,in controlling function two values are checked, one value is updated after a service call.so the resultant view is showing as disabled as the function is called before and the async call updates the values later.

So I want my view to call that disabling controller function later after my async call is finished.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="shouldDisableNewStrategyLink()" id="newStrategy">
              Create New Strategy</button>

$scope.shouldDisableNewStrategyLink= function(){
   return !$scope.currentVenue.isEdit || !mapsAvailable;
}
```

Here the variable mapsAvailable updates later on finishes of async http call.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ng-disabled="myAsyncCall(shouldDisableNewStrategyLink())"`

Where:

```
$scope.myAsyncCall = function(callback){
  $http.get(blah blah blah).then(
       callback(err,data);
}

$scope.shouldDisableNewStrategyLink = function(err,data){
  //do equivalent of return !$scope.currentVenue.isEdit || !mapsAvailable; here
}
```

Comment: The AsynCall is called from somewhere in the controller.
Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: I would like to help you solve this issue. Let me know if you still would like help.